# Sending User Data Parameters via Pixel

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

I have some user data parameters from Facebook's Marketing API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/server-side-api/parameters/user-data#external-id) that I wish to send using Pixel (fbq function)

Let's take one of the user data parameter - external_id
I am currently doing something like this -

```
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {external_id: 1234})
```

The documentation on the aforementioned url states that you can send these values using fbq('init') function, but I wasn't sure if its applicable with fbq('track') function too.

On another note, recently I got this mail from facebook that "Your server is sending the external_id parameter for your AddToCart event inside the custom_data field section of your payload. External_id is invalid unless it is sent as user data field"

What could be the reason for it? the documentation states you don't need to wrap external_id inside user_data field if sending through pixel. Is this issue message incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any issues passing the external_id. Maybe look at the snippet, you might have an error in there. Here's what I am using for the Page View event.

```js
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
      'em':'some@email.com', // Email
      'external_id': user12345 // User ID
      });
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

[image: Page View Pixel Result]

Comment: But I don't know the external_id when I initialize the pixel! The user is a new user most of the time. I have a single page app! It can be sent via the server side API so it should be possible to send with a pixel Purchase event.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Well put! Yes this is my exact issue! Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @TomLehman If you don't have it you can't send it here. I'm sending it with purchases but couldn't get around this chicken and egg problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not like if it is documented anywhere or is recommended by Facebook, but you can call `init` again at a later point in time with additional info.

So you can call `init` the normal default way first:

`fbq('init', 'XXXXX')`

And at a later point in time, when you have obtained additional user data, you can call `init` again basically enriching the already running `fbq` instance with additional data:

`fbq('init', 'XXXXX', { external_id: 1234, em: 'foo@example.com' } )`

Only caveat is that you have to send an event after this additional `init` call, otherwise the provided data will not be sent to Facebook.

Comment: Does anyone know if calling fbq('init') more than once causes problems with Pixel?

Comment: I'm using it actively and there are no problems. Let us know if you would find any, but at the end of the day sending events through `fbq` is a rather simple operation. It fires a network requests mapping the init and event parameters into query variables.
What kind of problems do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My concern is there is no documentation suggesting 'init' can be called more than once. It could cause side effects on their analytics such as duplicate page views for instance.

Comment: I understand that, but I looked at the source code, debugged step-by-step and it does nothing bad. Basically it adds any new information from the subsequent `init` call to the working memory, and events following that will include all the previous and the added parameters. Note that `init` does not send any events itself, so you can call it 100 times, there will be no data sent to FB servers. Data is only sent when you are firing events.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I shall try it and see what happens